# VBA EXCEL IF ELSE

Tags: excel, vba

Hello can anyone give me an idea on how to code this thing im stucked up here ..like If ComboBox1="STRING" Then TextBox1.value.... i dont know how to put this but i want the value of textbox1 to be save it on the cell of another worksheet what would be the possible way to do that? thnx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the value of a cell to be a string (e.g. `TextBox1.Value`) by something like:

```
... Then Worksheets("your_sheetname").Range("X5").Value = TextBox1.Value
```